# Pandas dataframe: how to drop rows that start with any number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to drop rows that start with any number, please?

I have this code but it doesn't work.

```
df = df[~df['column name'].isnumber()]
```

Comment: `df[~df['column name'].str[0].str.isdigit()]`

Comment: Alternately `df[df['column name'].str.contains('^\D')]`

Comment: Thank you both! I tested both lines and they work!

Answer (score 0):

df[~df['column name'].str[0].str.isdigit()]

or

df[df['column name'].str.contains('^\D')]

Answered by @anky and @ G. Anderson